# python request.get response object to download xlsx file from url saves excel file but file is smaller and not accessible

Tags: python, file, url, download, python-requests

Although I use stackoverflow regularly to solve problems, this is my first post :). I hope you can help!

I have a link that automatically downloads a `.xlsx` file. You get directed to a simple screen with a link if the download does not start automatically.
I can download the file and save it to disk.

However, the `.xlsx` file that is saved is smaller (2kb vs 6kb) and I cannot open it. When I open it with LibreOffice Calc it asks to select a language to use for import and then nothing happens.

Maybe some encoding/decoding problem?

I have tried several different methods to retrieve the file and save it to disk from various threads, but often with the same result.

This is my code:

```py
resp = requests.get(url)

with open('filename.xlsx', 'wb') as output:
  output.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: Perhaps you are downloading a redirect to the file not the file itself. If you open the file in a text editor do you see JavaScript code?

Comment: Thanks for answering! It looks like html code. I found a link inside the code (after "meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url = THE_LINK"> and when I use that in the script I can download the file correctly. I retrieve the link from an email and would like to automate the download with that link. It seems the link is inside resp.content??

Comment: If I place "&direct=1" behind the url it works just fine. Previously I've also tried 'resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)' , but this does not change anything.